# gdm greeter configuration: Exclude all *except* for one specific user

Tags: security, gnome, login, gdm, privacy

I have Googled this one and tried so many combinations, with no success.

I need the GDM login greeter to display one and only one username.  In effect, what I need is something like this in **/etc/gdm/custom.conf**:

```
[greeter]
ExcludeAll=true
Include=guest
```

This does not work, however, because ExcludeAll is not a valid option.  IncludeAll=false does nothing either.  I've tried every combination that I can think of.

Despite being discouraged, I modified **/etc/gdm/gdm.schemas**, trying a variety of combinations similar to the above.  No go.

I am aware of:

```
gconftool-2 --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --direct --type bool --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list true
```

but this is not an applicable solution, as it removes the user list completely.  I need one specific username to appear.

The only practical solution I can find is to, upon user login, run a script which will append that username to the "Exclude" list in **/etc/gdm/custom.conf**.  This is hacky, and not preferable.

This is for a public-use machine.  People can log in with their LDAP accounts if they have them, or they can select "Guest" from the login screen.  The people who log in with their LDAP accounts should NOT have their names visible on the login screen, but the "Guest" option must remain.

Using gnome 2.28.

Comment: See: [How to hide users from the GDM login screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen)

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I meant in my message.  I know how to exclude specific users, and I know how to hide all users, but I *don't* know how to exclude *ALL but one* user.

Comment: Try using the link I gave to hide 1 User first.  When you successfully hide 1 user, change the line that hides the one user to include 2 usernames etc until you've hidden all but the one you want.  Personally I would take a different approach.  See Possible Answer below.

Comment: We have thousands of users and can't maintain a list of exclusions.

Comment: Then read my answer below... If you can't do that, put the "thousands of users" in a group, and hide the group

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding all but one user why can you not create just 1 user for all lab pc's, and install that user locally on each machine?  Then enable sharing this way:

If a user is on the LDAP Server allow the user to login to devices etc while logged in as guest, by providing their LDAP credentials, only when needed instead of allowing them to login via GDM